# Error trying to run a Flutter WEB app, using Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-remote-config

I have a Flutter app, using Firebase, running just fine on iOS and Android (emulators and physical devices).

I'm trying to compile and run it for the **web**, and I get an error when trying to use Firebase services (specifically ConfigRemote but I suspect it's a Firebase general issue).

This is the first time I try to compile for web, with Firebase, so my knowledge here is quite limited...

What I've done:

1. Added a web app on the Firebase console
2. Copied the required scripts into the body tag (index.html)
3. Added all dependencies scripts (index.html)

```
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

The error I'm getting (at **await ui.webOnlyInitializePlatform()**):

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at Object.throwNullValueError (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:5314:15)
    at Object._notNull [as notNull] (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:5667:25)
    at new core.Duration.new (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:123963:168)
    at method_channel_firebase_remote_config.MethodChannelFirebaseRemoteConfig.new.setInitialValues (http://localhost:64231/packages/firebase_remote_config_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_remote_config.dart.lib.js:230:26)
    at Function.instanceFor (http://localhost:64231/packages/firebase_remote_config_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_remote_config.dart.lib.js:88:118)
    at firebase_remote_config.RemoteConfig.__.get [_delegate] (http://localhost:64231/packages/firebase_remote_config/firebase_remote_config.dart.lib.js:62:131)
    at firebase_remote_config.RemoteConfig.__.setConfigSettings (http://localhost:64231/packages/firebase_remote_config/firebase_remote_config.dart.lib.js:138:18)
    at _loadRemoteConfig (http://localhost:64231/packages/bla/main.dart.lib.js:299:26)
    at _loadRemoteConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39250:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39281:7)
    at Object._loadRemoteConfig (http://localhost:64231/packages/bla/main.dart.lib.js:293:18)
    at main$ (http://localhost:64231/packages/bla/main.dart.lib.js:288:18)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39230:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39087:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34073:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34633:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34671:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34513:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34536:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39374:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:39380:13)
    at http://localhost:64231/dart_sdk.js:34887:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote configs is not supported by Flutter Web https://firebase.flutter.dev

I'll also suggest you to delete the js script from your index.html and also taking care of the condition you're expecting from Remote Config to avoid more exceptions in your code.

Comment: This is no longer true, but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: same here, `RemoteConfig` is supported for web but the error is still there

Comment: From what I can see, RemoteConfig says that it supports Flutter Web, but there's little to no documentation on how it is. For example, there's absolutely no way to select Web/JS as a platform in Remote Config A/B Testing on Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Remote config is not currently supported on web, remove that form your index.html and inside your app, check if you are running on web or not before executing remote config logic.

i.e

```
void remoteConfigLogic(){
if(!kIsweb) runLogic();
}
```

`kIsweb` is a flutter boolean to tell you if the platform you are using is web or not.

Comment: The documentation says that it is now supported on web: https://firebase.flutter.dev/